# How to make to an image use all the screen not only the section

Tags: html, css

I've trying to set an image to use all the space in the screen but no matter what I try, it always leave the left side blank and only set the new size to the right. The image is not in the HTML file it's set only in css as background.
Here is the html and css snippet`

```
<section class='eg-main_image'>
            
            <h1 class="eg-text-white">lorem ipsum</h1>
            <h1 class="eg-text-white">lorem ipsum</h1>
            <h4 class="eg-text-white">lorem lorem lorem</h4>
            
        </section>
```

```
.eg-main_image{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #C04848;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(33,55,107,0.7), rgb(24,86,180,0.2)), url("../images/pictures/other.jpg"); 
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(33,55,107,0.7), rgb(31,76,144,0.2)), url("../images/pictures/self.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

The closest I got from succeded was using `left: -65%` and `width: 100vw;` but does not get responsive, also tried to use `background-position: 100% 100%;` and still does not work. What I want to do is to fill the background layer with the image using all the screen's width but being responsive. I will drop a picture for you can see exactly what i'm doing and what i'm trying to do.[image]

Comment: We will need more context. How is the `<section class='eg-main_image'>` element positioned in the page. Please provide a [MCVE] . We don't need the whole page  **just enough** to replicate the problem.

Comment: It is inside a `<nav>` that contains a lot of Media Queries and also has a `<div>` container that has other Media Queries. For more context only sending the files for you to look

Comment: That is what we are going to need more info on, those elements could have margin, padding, flex, other positioning attributes that will be affecting what you are seeing. There are too many potential variables to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background / Background-image covers only the area which is occupied by the element (in your case its section tag with eg-main_image class).
Can you please add a screenshot of inspecting this section tag?
Because it's not clear from the given code how much width this section is occupying

**Solution 1:** Make sure all the parent tags of this section tag also have width 100%

**solution 2:** Add these background styles in .eg-main_image:before OR .eg-main_image:after Pseudo elements, and then you can position this pseudo element absolute and have required width. Hope this makes sense :)